# Cannot Cast to my TV anymore

Tags: windows-10, tv

I have a Windows 10 Pro (version 1511) and a Samsung series 6 LED TV. I was able to right-click on a media file, select "Cast to device", and choose my TV from the menu, and this will play the media file on my TV.

For some reason, that I don't remember anymore, I deleted my PC from the list of multimedia devices on my TV, and since then (I guess) I lost the ability to play anything from this PC to the TV; it keeps trying to connect and fails eventually.

I tried to reset the TV, with the best of my knowledge, but this didn't help at all.

I don't know where the problem is now (with the PC or the TV) and appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

I have Samsung too. I just installed win10 home.the only way I can view on tv is hit source button on remote l had to do this on win7 and win8. There,probably are more ways to do it .But this works for me

Comment: Thanks for the option. My PC is not shown as media server, or something, on my TV. Besides, my question here is mainly about "Why it was working before and now it doesn't? How to make it work again?".